# When I try to create a custom message with annotation argument. I get [Syntax Error]

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, symfony4

The `createFormBuilder` pass through a class Called `RegisterValidation()`

```
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


class RegisterValidation extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank( message = 'Enter first name please.') //This parameter trows an error
     */
    public $firstName;

}
```

I'm learning annotations it looks very nice to use every day on a project. Unfortunately, this issue seems so specific that I cannot find any Symfony 4 documentation. I want to use a custom message to replace the default one.

Comment: What's the actual code? That's a comment, so shouldn't have any effect on your code.

Comment: Use double quotes `"` in PHP annotations

Comment: Also post error text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full error message is probably :

> [Syntax Error] Expected PlainValue, got ''' at position ***

As explained, your message in annotation should be between doubles quotes `"`.

```
class RegisterValidation extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Enter first name please.") // Message must be in double quotes
     */
    public $firstName;

}
```

Comment: You're an ace. Exactly that was exactly the problem! Thank you very much!